# How do i calculate a ball/paddle collision?

Tags: c, linux

```
typedef struct direction
{
    char q; // quadrant ( up_left, up_right, low_left, low_right )
    double c; // coefficient in degrees ( 0 .. 90 )
} bdir;

struct ball
{
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    bdir dir;
} mainball;

int ploc; // refers to paddle location
int jump; // refers to velocity

//ball_cycle is called somewhere from a real timer signal handler.
void ball_cycle( void )
{

    int paddle_hit_resolution = 0;

    if ( mainball.dir.q == up_left )
    {   //sin and cos from math.h
        mainball.xpos-=jump * cos( mainball.dir.c * PI / 180);
        mainball.ypos-=jump * sin( mainball.dir.c * PI / 180); 

        if( mainball.xpos < 0 )
        {
            mainball.dir.q = up_right;
        }

        if( mainball.ypos < 0 )
        {
            mainball.dir.q = low_left;
        }
        return;
    }   

    if ( mainball.dir.q == up_right )
    {
        mainball.xpos+=jump * cos( mainball.dir.c * PI / 180);
        mainball.ypos-=jump * sin( mainball.dir.c * PI / 180);

        if( mainball.xpos > window_x_size - BALL_WIDTH )
        {
            mainball.dir.q = up_left;   
        }
        if( mainball.ypos < 0 )
        {
            mainball.dir.q = low_right;
        }
        return;
    }   
    if ( mainball.dir.q == low_left )
    {
        mainball.xpos-=jump * cos( mainball.dir.c * PI / 180);
        mainball.ypos+=jump * sin( mainball.dir.c * PI / 180);

        if( mainball.xpos < 1 )
        {
            mainball.dir.q = low_right; 
        }

        if( mainball.ypos > window_y_size - ( BALL_HEIGHT + PADDLE_HEIGHT ) ) // paddle hit?
        {
            mainball.dir.q = up_left;

            if ( (mainball.xpos >= ploc ) && (mainball.xpos <= ploc + PADDLE_WIDTH ) )
            {
                score++;

/*
    this is where the question is about.
*/
            } else
            {
                lost();
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    if ( mainball.dir.q == low_right )
    {
        mainball.xpos+=jump * cos( mainball.dir.c * PI / 180);
        mainball.ypos+=jump * sin( mainball.dir.c * PI / 180);

        if( mainball.xpos > window_x_size - BALL_WIDTH)
        {
            mainball.dir.q = low_left;  
        }

        if( mainball.ypos > window_y_size - ( BALL_HEIGHT + PADDLE_HEIGHT )  ) //paddle hit?
        {
            mainball.dir.q = up_right;
            if ( (mainball.xpos >= ploc  ) && (mainball.xpos <= ploc + PADDLE_WIDTH ) )
            {
                score++;
/*
    here too.
*/
            } else
            {
                lost();
            }
        }
        return;
    }   

    return;
}
```

above code is a snippet from a paddle / ball game a am writing for my education.

there are two places ( see comments ) where this question is about.

when the ball moves towards the lower part of the screen ( when mainball.dir.q is low_left or low_right )

the ball either hits the paddle and moves to another quadrant ( up_left or up_right ) or, it misses the paddle, lost() is called and
game is over.

at start mainball.dir.c equals 45. ( 45 degrees, so when the ball hits the wall of the screen, it also bounces 45 degrees towards another quadrant ).

in my case PADDLE_WIDTH equals 120 (pixels). so i could resolute the paddle in (ex) 180 parts. eg.

```
resolution = ( (mainball.xpos - ploc) * 180 ) / PADDLE_WIDTH
```

( so whatever place the ball hits the paddle, will be indicated by a value between 0 and 180, regardless of the paddle width, right? )

at the two places i need to calculate a collision. ( the paddle has a velocity, defined as a global variable somewhere else )

( after the ball has collided with the paddle, i need to have a new angle so the game starts looking smooth. )

what would be the new mainball.dir.c value after the ball collides with the paddle?

i guess a resolution value, and even maybe the velocity should be used by calculating the new mainball.dir.c.

Comment: can you narrow down your question and code? looking too long.

Comment: Would probably be better on [gamedev SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I think I got what you are asking, it sounds like you are interested in getting the direction of the ball after a collision with the paddle.

The way that I've seen this done frequently is to maintain the velocity in the x-direction and y-direction, and assume that all collisions are perfectly elastic (thus allowing conservation of both momentum and kinetic energy).  The benefit of doing this, is that collision resolution is handled by four simple cases :

- collision with the top of the playing area, velocity in the x-direction is not affected by the collision, and velocity in the y-direction is reversed; i.e. v_{y}^{'} = -v_{y}.
- collision with the left-hand side of the playing area, velocity in the y-direction is not affected by the collision, and velocity in the x-direction is reversed; i.e. x_{x}^{'} = -v_{x}.
- collision with the bottom of the playing area (or the paddle), velocity in the x-direction is not affected by the collision, and velocity in the y-direction is reversed.
- collision with the right-hand side of the the playing area, velocity in the y-direction is not affected by the collision and velocity in the x-direction is reversed.

The beauty of this is that we avoid expensive operations like sin and cos, as well as avoiding floating point operations.

Comment: When i start using this technique, isn't it the fact that the angle of impact is the same as the angle of outcome? The main idea is that the paddle gives the ball a pitch so the angle changes.

Comment: Yes, the angle of incidence is equal to the angle of reflection.  I was thinking of games such as breakout where the paddle moves along the bottom of the screen (and is parallel to the bottom of the game field).  I didn't realize that you paddle was tilted (if I'm understanding your comment).  When I've implemented a breakout clone, if I want to modify the pitch I do so by making small changes to the y-velocity.  For example, and very simplistically, I had a paddle parallel to the bottom and  would use the distance from the paddle midpoint as a modifier to the y-velocity.

Comment: i understand why this topic is voted down. while surfing i see an awful lot of ( mostly) the same questions. I need to do some better homework on game physics and collisions. peace.